# Blue box on Microsoft Word Enter

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office365

I have MS Word for Mac, from Office 365, 2017 version 15.34, I have a document where, each time I hit enter a blue box appears with it's own text format, I can avoid this box to appear, what's going on? How can I remove this behaviour?
[image]

Comment: Does it happen with just the one document?  If so, what happens if you open the document, select the entire contents, copy, and paste it into a new blank document?

Comment: It happens if I copy the content and paste it in a new file.